# Dependency Injection with Koin in iOS (KMM)

Tags: swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, koin

I'm using Koin in a KMM project. On Android it's working as expected but on iOS I have to create a wrapper around each component I want to inject, something like this (Logger component as an example):

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T> getKoinInstance() =
    object : KoinComponent {
        val value: T by inject()
    }.value

object LoggeriOS {
    private val logger = getKoinInstance<Logger>()
    fun logger() = logger
}
```

Then I can do this on iOS:

```swift
let logger = LoggeriOS.shared.logger()
logger.i(msg: "Hello World")
```

Question: is there a better way to do this without a wrapper class specifically for iOS?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly provide extensions to Koin class from kmm module and then in ios side directly use them.

**Step 1** Define extension for Inside kmm ios module

```
val Koin.logger: Logger
  get() = get() // second get() is from koin
```

**Step 2**

And then define method for starting koin from ios side, Koin.swift file and save global instance of koin

```
func startKoin() {

    let koinApplication = DependencyInjectionKt.doInitKoinIOS()
    // _koin is Koin instance
    _koin = koinApplication.koin
}


//koin is a global instance of Koin, use it to get dependencies
private var _koin: Koin_coreKoin? = nil
var koin: Koin_coreKoin {
    return _koin!
}
```

**Step 3**
And then in iosApp.swift file

```
@main
struct iOSApp: App {
   init() { startKoin()  }
}
```

ANd then you can use koin instance from Koin.swift anywhere just like this

```
  koin.logger // this will use the extension you defined in kmm module in first step and will provide you Logger
```